# Graphics not loading from CSS file in my ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, css

I have this index.aspx page that isn't loading graphics from the CSS.  The text 'Test' is loading fine.

What am I doing wrong?

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="chinatownexperience.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body-1">
        <div id="topblank"><p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#000;
    background: #9c0000;
    background: url('images/Chinatown-lgebg.png') left top; 
}

#body-1 {
    width: 880px; height: 1500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden; 
}

#topblank {
    float: left;
    width: 880px;
    height:266px;
    background: url('images/WebsiteTop.png') repeat-y left top;
}
```

I must be missing something silly?

Comment: added a / to each image url and it worked.  Sorry guys should have tested this before.

Comment: ^ http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hi5TFP-EQ1c/UFSn8-dxF_I/AAAAAAAAAGk/k9Q7Y9UVNgc/s1600/FUUUUUUUUU_The_World_by_FattyMcFatters.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this examples u can addressing from root and dont use single cot like this

```
background:url(/yourProjectRoot/cssFolderNameOrFile.../yourImage.*)
```

Comment: Are you suggesting putting the image in the CSS folder?

Answer (score 0):

The path to the images must be relative to the location of the CSS file not the HTML/ASP/whatever file. You should point to the correct location of the images.

Example :

if you use directory structure like this :

```
- root\
|- css\
|- images\
page.extension
```

Then the path on the CSS file should be :

```
background: url('../images/whatever.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your paths need to be relative to the stylesheet, not the root.

```
root 
  -css/styles.css
  -images/
  index.html
```

So if you had the above structure you would need this in your CSS

```
background: url('../images/your_image.png');
```

*(worth noting that .htc files in CSS should have a path relative to the root. Handy for old browser fixes)*